# данные не сохраняются в базу данных pymongoDB

Tags: python, discord.py, mongodb, asyncio, pymongo

Пытаюсь cдeлaть каналы привата, используя базу данных MongoDB, весь функционал вроде работает, до момента когда надо сохранять данные в бд. В консоли жалуется на строку `t_channel = bot.get_channel(private.find_one({'_id': member.id})['text_id'])`, понятно, что оно не может получить данные из бд, но я не могу понять почему они не сохраняются, ошибки наводящей на это нет.
Полную ошибку из консоли приложил ниже как и ивент on_voice_state_update, оставив комментарий возле строки, на которую жалуется консоль и строк с бд.

```
import pymongo

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Corrygan:pEk-aku-RSN-SyU@otmorozokcluster.qagkthv.mongodb.net/")
db = cluster['PrivateDB']
private = db['PrivateCollection']

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

    if after.channel is not None:
        if after.channel.id == 1200091472138084402: #id создания привата
            guild = bot.get_guild(1105205137837916170) #id сервера
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name='Private')
            v_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'Приват ({member.display_name})', category=category)
            t_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'Выдача прав ({member.display_name})', category=category)

            embed = discord.Embed(
                title='',
                description='Вы успешно создали свой приватный канал!\nЧтобы дать возможность заходить к вам используйте команду `+perm <user>`\nЧтобы забрать права используйте команду `+unperm <user>`',
                color=0x000000
            )
            await t_channel.send(embed=embed)

            await v_channel.set_permissions(member, view_channel=True, connect=True, speak=True, stream=True, kick_members=True, mute_members=True, priority_speaker=True)
            await t_channel.set_permissions(member, view_channel=True)
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=1105205137837916170)
            await v_channel.set_permissions(role, view_channel=False)
            await t_channel.set_permissions(role, view_channel=False)

            await member.move_to(v_channel)

            private_post = {
                '_id': member.id,
                'text_id':t_channel.id,
                'voice_id':v_channel.id,
            }

            if not private.count_documents({'_id':member.id}) == 1:
                private.insert_one(private_post)
            else:
                private.delete_one({'_id':member.id})      

    if before.channel:
        t_channel = bot.get_channel(private.find_one({'_id': member.id})['text_id']) --сюда жалуется
        v_channel = bot.get_channel(private.find_one({'_id': member.id})['voice_id'])
```

> [2024-02-03 17:29:30] [ERROR   ] discord.client: Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\bot\main.py", line 66, in on_voice_state_update
> t_channel = bot.get_channel(private.find_one({'_id': member.id})['text_id'])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1506, in find_one
> for result in cursor.limit(-1):
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1264, in next
> if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1155, in _refresh
> self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1823, in _ensure_session
> return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1766, in __start_session
> self._topology._check_implicit_session_support()
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 573, in _check_implicit_session_support
> self._check_session_support()
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 589, in _check_session_support
> self._select_servers_loop(
> File "C:\Users\Хозяин\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 259, in _select_servers_loop
> raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-00.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-01.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms),SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-02.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 65be4da40ff039f27428b7b6, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-00.qagkthv.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-00.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-01.qagkthv.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-01.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>, <ServerDescription ('ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-02.qagkthv.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('SSL handshake failed: ac-cgv7lf9-shard-00-02.qagkthv.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1000) (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms, connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

Comment: В целом по трейсбеку видно, что проблема с `SSL` и `handshake`-ом, следуют копнуть в эту сторону. Попробуйте поиграться с атрибутами `ssl=True` и `tls=True` или `False` для каждого из вариантов и проследить за результатами. В документации в классе `MongoClient` там описан целый раздел об `ssl`. В любом случае оставлять незащищенное соединение - вариант не очень.

Comment: Про какую доментацию MongoClient идет речь? Я мб что-то не то искал
Можно ссылку?

Comment: О, я сам столкнулся с такой проблемой недавно. Во-первых изучите этот материал, возможно он вам поможет больше чем мне: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484890/ssl-handshake-issue-with-pymongo-on-python3. В моём же случае проблема была в настройках `Network Access` на самом сайте. У меня был установлен конкретный IP adress, после смены на 0.0.0.0/0 запросы стали приходить. Однако вам стоит так же знать что данное решение может подойти для тестирования, однако для прода не рекомендуется насколько мне известно.

Comment: Что касается причины данной проблемы у меня, могу только предположить что это связано с серым динамическим IP адресом который предоставляет мне провайдер, ещё причиной может служить работающий VPN на компьютере, но в моём случае не было разницы включён он или нет, запросы всё равно падали.

Comment: @Corrygan, если вы используете `pycharm`, то удержите `Ctrl` и нажмите левой кнопкой мыши на класс `MongoClient`. Вы попадете в исходный код класса и там будет документация. Если VS Code, то, наверное, существует и аналогичный способ просмотреть исходники

Answer (score 0):

Удается ли подключиться к этой БД через mongo-express клиента? Если через другого клиента подключиться удается, стоит попробовать явно указать, что надо использовать TLC сертификат, как советовали в сообщении выше:

```
import certifi
ca = certifi.where()

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.xxxxx.mongodb.net/xyzdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority", 
                             tlsCAFile=ca)
```

Если подключение и через mongo-express не удается, то стоит проверить конфигурацию самой БД.